# Magento resource_product_action model vs catalog/product model

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

What is the difference between..

**catalog product model**

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku','sku');

if ($product) {
    $product->setPrice(50.33);
    $product->save();
}
```

**resource product action model**

```
$action = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_product_action');
$action->updateAttributes(array($product_id), array(
    'price' => 11000.22,
), $storeId);
```

Does any one of them related to Price Indexes? If I have price index as "Update on Save" will the price index get refreshed automatically for either of the methods above?